# Jupyter lab sorting

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a csv file which contains airports in the world, columns with the country names, city names, elevation, regions, runways so on. I am trying to display the city names which has at least 5 runways accumulated, and sort the city list by the number of runways in descending order, and also display the number of runway in each [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ8mq.jpg)city. I can make the least 5 runways but I can not sort them decreasing, could you help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it;

```
byrunways = df.sort_values(by = 'runways', ascending = False)
df_indexed = byrunways.set_index('city')
condition = df_indexed['runways'] > 4
display(df_indexed[condition]['runways'])

----BUUTTTTTT-----`But`
```

the point is what if the city has multiple airports?